# English Language Dictionary api

Tags: c#, .net, api, dictionary, linguistics

Is there a public API which would let me lookup definitions for words ? I've been searching for this for a bit but it's getting mixed up with the dictionary datastructure. I'm planing on using it in a c# app.

Thanks

Comment: Google is your friend. Use `define: word`.

Comment: @Margus I was looking for a public api. don't want to parse html whose format is not fixed.

Answer (score 7):

If you are language agnostic, you could try

Ruby WordNet

http://deveiate.org/projects/Ruby-WordNet/

and check out the WordNet project in general,

http://wordnet.princeton.edu/

for .NET...

http://opensource.ebswift.com/WordNet.Net/

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm working on a c# application.

Comment: Doesn't look like a public web API. I have a database-based solution currently but i'm trying to move away from it as it's need to be constantly updated.